# How to fix undefined offset and undefined index

Tags: php

Hello I have this code which selects from a list of 20 items 12 and from those 12 1 is randomly selected and echoed:

```
    class Gamble
    {
        public static function doPointsCheck()
        {
            global $Gamble;

            $Gamble_points = '2';

        if($Gamble_points <= 1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        public static function Spin()
        {
            global $Wheel;

            if(!self::doPointsCheck())
            return 'You need way too more points to gamble';
            else
            {
                $Result = array();

                    $Result = range(1, 12);
                    shuffle($Result);
                    $Result = array_slice($Result, 0, 20);

                $SendToCheck = self::CheckPrize($Result);

            }
        }

        public static function CheckPrize($Array)
        {
            global $Wheel;

            echo '<h1>List of items you can win today:</h1><form action="class.MysticWheel.php" method="post">';

            for($i = 1; $i <= count($Array); $i++)
            {
                $Won = '<p>'.$Wheel[$Array[$i]]['pseudo'].'</p>';
                echo $Won;
            }

            echo '<input name="Feeling lucky" type="submit" value="Feeling Lucky" /></form>';

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

                $i = rand( 1, 12 );
                $Prize = '<p>'.$Wheel[$Array[$i]]['pseudo'].'</p>';
                echo $Prize;

            }

        }
    }
```

When I test it I recieve the following error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 12 on line 54

Notice: Undefined index:  on line 54

So i won't show the last item, it will only show 11 possible items that could have been won and get the notice.

How can I fix it?

Comment: PHP arrays start with index 0.  So, if `$myArray` has 12 items in it, the first one is `$myArray[0]`, and the las one is `$myArray[11]`.

Comment: Every array starts with 0..

Comment: @Nickparsa `===` works fine.

Comment: @SuperScript i turned my for to 0 but still shows the notice

Comment: You also need the `< count($Array)` instead of `<= count($Array)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$Result = range(1, 12);
-->
foreach (range(1, 12) as $number) {
    $Result[] = $number;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: This will return 24 values instead of 12 that I need and they are repeated as my funcion intends those 12 values not to be repeated.

Comment: Your answers would be much better if you **elaborated more** on what you did.  Explain what's happening.